# DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport - Returns nothing when used on older computers, but works on newer computers. Ram Management?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I currently have to load many SQL_Developer 'Loader' files into an Access DB on bi-weekly basis and the machine that does the import can be random. The code below works fine on a newer computer (i5 16gb ram, i7 16gb ram). For some reason though it will not load anything into the designated table after I call imexImport_LoaderFile a few times on a less than great computer (i3 8gb of ram, various laptops). It works for the first few and then as it goes down the list of calls to the imexImport_LoaderFile function it will just stop on a random one and not load the information into the access table. If I restart the computer it can get further down the list or imexImport_LoaderFile calls. The table it fails on is random, but after each subsequent try it gets less and less further down the list of imexImport_LoaderFile calls. I can then give up on the sad computer walk over to a newer model and it loads just fine from begging to end. I am assuming its a memory management issue, but I am clearing my objects in the function so I'm really stumped here. Any input at all would be amazing. Oh, and the source file has to be LOADER files which is why I am even using RunSavedImportExport.

```
Sub XYZ
do things..

ColNames = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
CurrentTempTableMaxDate = imexImport_LoaderFile(FilePath, FileName, AccessTableNameTemp, AccessTableName, ColNames)
If CurrentTempTableMaxDate <= DBTablesMaxDate Then Err.Raise Number:=10002
ColNames = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
CurrentTempTableMaxDate = imexImport_LoaderFile(FilePath, FileName, AccessTableNameTemp, AccessTableName, ColNames)
If CurrentTempTableMaxDate <= DBTablesMaxDate Then Err.Raise Number:=10002
ColNames = Array("a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5", "f6", "g7")
CurrentTempTableMaxDate = imexImport_LoaderFile(FilePath, FileName, AccessTableNameTemp, AccessTableName, ColNames)
If CurrentTempTableMaxDate <= DBTablesMaxDate Then Err.Raise Number:=10002

do other things...
end sub


Public Function imexImport_LoaderFile(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal FileName As String, ByVal AccessTempTableName As String, ByVal AccessTableName As String, ByVal ColNames As Variant) As Date
Dim name_of_spec As String
Dim imexObjs As Object
Dim ColNumber As Integer
Dim xml As String
name_of_spec = "imspec" & FileName
On Error Resume Next
If CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Count > 0 Then
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Set imexObjs = CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications
        For Each imexObj In imexObjs
            If imexObj.NAME = name_of_spec Then imexObj.Delete
        Next
        Set imexObjs = Nothing
    End If
End If

If TableExist(AccessTempTableName) Then DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable = acDefault, AccessTempTableName
LoaderFile_Cleanup (FilePath & FileName)

xml = ""
xml = xml & "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "<ImportExportSpecification Path=" & Chr(34) & FilePath & FileName & Chr(34) & " xmlns=""urn:www.microsoft.com/office/access/imexspec"">" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "   <ImportText TextFormat=""Delimited"" FirstRowHasNames=""0"" FieldDelimiter=""|"" CodePage=""437"" Destination=" & Chr(34) & AccessTempTableName & Chr(34) & " >" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "      <DateFormat DateOrder=""MDY"" DateDelimiter=""/"" TimeDelimiter="":"" FourYearDates=""true"" DatesLeadingZeros=""false"" />" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "      <NumberFormat DecimalSymbol=""."" />" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "           <Columns PrimaryKey=""{none}"">" & vbCrLf

For ColNumber = LBound(ColNames) To UBound(ColNames)
xml = xml & "                    <Column Name=""Col" & ColNumber + 1 & """ FieldName=""" & ColNames(ColNumber) & """ Indexed=""NO""               SkipColumn=""false"" DataType=""Text""    Width=""12"" />" & vbCrLf
Next ColNumber

xml = xml & "         </Columns>" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "     </ImportText>" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "</ImportExportSpecification>"
'''debug.print xml
CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Add name_of_spec, Trim(xml)
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport name_of_spec
imexImport_LoaderFile = DMax("[MEGA_EFFDT]", "[" & AccessTempTableName & "]") 'Format(DMax("[EXPORTDATE]", "[" & AccessTempTableName & "]"), "mm/dd/yyyy") 'CDate(Int(DMax("[EXPORTDATE]", "[" & AccessTempTableName & "]")))
''debug.print imexImport_LoaderFile
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, AccessTempTableName, CID_BE_Dir & AccessTempTableName, True

CleanExitTask:
Set imexObjs = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so this isn't really a fix, but its a work around that seems to work on the network I am on. I'm only posting it here in case it helps someone else because this has been a nightmare on my end. My best guess is its a network/anti virus issues when using the imex spec and muliple large files. Anyway, my workaround was to just add a retry. Now when the import fails it just trys it again. So far it has worked on every second try when and if it comes up.

```
Public Function imexImport_LoaderFile(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal FileName As String, ByVal AccessTempTableName As String, ByVal AccessTableName As String, ByVal ColNames As Variant) As Date
Dim name_of_spec As String
Dim imexObjs As Object
Dim ColNumber As Integer
Dim xml As String
name_of_spec = "imspec" & FileName
On Error Resume Next

retry_import:
If CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Count > 0 Then
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Set imexObjs = CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications
        For Each imexObj In imexObjs
            If imexObj.NAME = name_of_spec Then imexObj.Delete
        Next
        Set imexObjs = Nothing
    End If
End If


LoaderFile_Cleanup (FilePath & FileName)

xml = ""
xml = xml & "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "<ImportExportSpecification Path=" & Chr(34) & FilePath & FileName & Chr(34) & " xmlns=""urn:www.microsoft.com/office/access/imexspec"">" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "   <ImportText TextFormat=""Delimited"" FirstRowHasNames=""0"" FieldDelimiter=""|"" CodePage=""437"" AppendToTable=" & Chr(34) & AccessTempTableName & Chr(34) & " >" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "      <DateFormat DateOrder=""MDY"" DateDelimiter=""/"" TimeDelimiter="":"" FourYearDates=""true"" DatesLeadingZeros=""false"" />" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "      <NumberFormat DecimalSymbol=""."" />" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "           <Columns PrimaryKey=""{none}"">" & vbCrLf

For ColNumber = LBound(ColNames) To UBound(ColNames)
        xml = xml & "                    <Column Name=""Col" & ColNumber + 1 & """ FieldName=""" & ColNames(ColNumber) & """ Indexed=""NO""               SkipColumn=""false"" DataType=""Text""    Width=""12"" />" & vbCrLf
Next ColNumber

xml = xml & "         </Columns>" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "     </ImportText>" & vbCrLf
xml = xml & "</ImportExportSpecification>"
'''debug.print xml
CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Add name_of_spec, Trim(xml)
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport name_of_spec
DoEvents
imexImport_LoaderFile = DMax("[MEGA_EFFDT]", "[" & AccessTempTableName & "]") 'Format(DMax("[EXPORTDATE]", "[" & AccessTempTableName & "]"), "mm/dd/yyyy") 'CDate(Int(DMax("[EXPORTDATE]", "[" & AccessTempTableName & "]")))
''debug.print imexImport_LoaderFile

If DCount("EMPLID", AccessTempTableName) = 0 Then
    If MsgBox(FileName & " import failed. Would you like to retry?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        GoTo retry_import
    End If
End If
CleanExitTask:
Set imexObjs = Nothing
End Function
```